# Unable to access postgres remotely from Azure VM

Tags: postgresql, port, azure

I'm trying to access a postgres database remotely and I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I've installed a Gen 2 linux VM in Azure with Ubuntu 14.04 and installed postgres.  SSH works remotely, and psql works fine while remoted in.

Steps I've taken:

1. updated `postgresql.conf` `listen_addresses` to be `'*'` and confirmed via `psql` and `show listen_addresses` that it's listening to `*`.
2. Updated `pg_hba.conf` by adding `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`.
3. Added an inbound allow rule in the Azure Network security group for port 5432. [image]
4. Restarted postgres/ubuntu.

After these steps, I'm able to work with and access psql just fine, but whenever I attempt to remotely connect to the instance via pgAdmin3, I get an error stating that the connection timed out.

Further, when I use a port checker remotely, port 5432 is reported as closed.

What am I missing/doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Here is the current output of `iptables -S`
[image]

Comment: Have you also checked if you have any firewall configured in the server itself? What is the output of `iptables -S`?

Comment: @bangal, I'm a little out of my depths on the firewall configure.  At one point I had added an IP table entry, but my updated question has the current output of `iptables -S`.  I don't see my entry for 5432...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need to use iptables-persistent

See

http://postgresql.freeideas.cz/install-postgresql-9-5-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I've added that to the mix, but turns out that wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So, for some reason, this is an Azure issue.  I opened port `5432`, but that didn't work.  In a move of desperation, I've opened 1024-65535, and now I can connect.  Clearly I'm missing something related to the usage of inbound rules. While this does fix my issue, it's clearly not a best practice.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue on Azure VM - Linux. I tried below

> Change PG_hba.conf
>   Change postgres.conf
>   Add Rule in Firewall using Azure Portal

but was unable to connect using pgadmin. But once I run below command I was able to connect.

iptables -I INPUT 1 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT

Above work for me absolutely. After spending so many hours :)

All the best !!

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, the port is somewhere between 25000-27500.  You could keep trying to narrow it down but that seemed good enough for me for now - better than exposing every port. I also have another rule that leaves port 5432 open.